# Now I have been trying the linebreak in comment box on askubuntu and it does not work for me here

Tags: discussion

Now I have been trying the linebreak in comment box on askubuntu and it does not work for me here

[Linebreaks](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#linebreaks)

***End a line with two spaces to add a 
 linebreak:***

How do I love thee?
Let me count the ways

When I do this nothing happens; everything remains on the same line

**Let me explain what I do**

Maybe I do not understand what is required
I write say:

testing the formatting[here I hit the space bar twice; then go Shift+Enter and start writing my second line]
and it should work right?

This is what I get:

testing the formatting and it should work right?

when i publish **and no linebreak**

**SO**  i thought maybe they mean 2 **line** spaces
and did the same again using Shift+Enter   twice

...and same fiasco ...

So what am i doing wrong ...    ***or has the linebreak function been deleted?***

Thanx for clarifications    shan

Comment: Comments do not support line breaks, never have and never will. The markdown that they support is limited.

Comment: ok so it does not support it which is never mentioned in the guide
http://askubuntu.com/editing-help#linebreaks   unless i missed something

Comment: Yes, you missed the section on comments: http://askubuntu.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Comment: than you muru  
all in the detail :]

Answer (score 3):

You can't have blank lines in the comments. Comments support a very limited subset of the formatting functionality of Stack Exchange. This is as it should be. Comments are for short messages, requesting clarification or making an observation.

If what you need to write can't be displayed properly as a comment, that's a good indication that you shouldn't be posting it as a comment. It should probably be a question or an answer instead.